# Variable showing undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm actually clueless, I'm launching this javascript code with node and then I expect it to show up only the number 100 and 69 but this is the output when it first starts:
`undefined undefined 100 69 100 69`. The first time the variables show as undefined.. what am i doing wrong?

Also, this code is just for testing purposes..

```
startCrash();

var currentCrashNumber = 100;
var currentCrashSpeed = 100;

function startCrash(){  
    sendCrashNumber();

    setInterval(function(){ 
        if(currentCrashSpeed > 0){
            currentCrashSpeed = currentCrashSpeed+-1;
        }else{
            clearInterval(this);
        }
    }, 1000);   
}

var lijntjespeed = 69;
function sendCrashNumber() {    
    console.log(currentCrashNumber);
    console.log(lijntjespeed);

    io.sockets.emit('message', {
        crashMultiplier: currentCrashNumber,
        type: 'updateCrash'
    });

    setTimeout(sendCrashNumber, currentCrashSpeed);     
}
```

Comment: "currentCrashSpeed = currentCrashSpeed+-1;" Do you want increment or decrement?

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares +- is the same as minus, it's whatever, decrement :) (EDIT: so it should go faster)

Comment: @Dinesh I'm not quite sure what you are getting at?

Comment: yes, but the code becomes unnecessarily less readable when not just using minus

Comment: @MartinDev where you call the function `startCrash`?

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares just on the top of the file, to launch all of the code.

Comment: That's the problem! Take a look at my answer :)

Comment: `clearInterval(this);` does not work because `this` is not set to the interval handle.

Comment: @jfriend00 then how would I do it, like this InterVar = setInter.. clearInterval(InterVar); ?

Comment: @MartinDev - yes that's how you do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is related to [`variable hoisting`](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript), since you call `startCrash` at the top of the code and, at this point, the variables `currentCrashNumber` and `currentCrashSpeed` are not initialized yet. That happens because the declaration of those variables are hoisted to the top of the code, so when the function is called, they are undefined at first.

This is the behaviour of your code after hoisting:

```
var currentCrashNumber; // undefined
var currentCrashSpeed; // undefined
var lijntjespeed; // undefined

startCrash();

currentCrashNumber = 100;
currentCrashSpeed = 100;
lijntjespeed = 69;

function startCrash(){  
    sendCrashNumber();

    setInterval(function(){ 
        if(currentCrashSpeed > 0){
            currentCrashSpeed = currentCrashSpeed+-1;
        }else{
            clearInterval(this);
        }
    }, 1000);   
}

...
```

Just move down the call for `startCrash` and it will work as expected.

Another issue in the code, pointed out by [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00), is in the `clearInterval` call from `startCrash` function. In your code, `this` is passed as parameter, while it needs to be a time handler.

To fix this, you can assign the return of `setInterval` (which is a timer) to a variable and use it instead:

```
function startCrash(){  
    sendCrashNumber();

    var timer = setInterval(function(){ 
        if(currentCrashSpeed > 0){
            currentCrashSpeed = currentCrashSpeed+-1;
        }else{
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);   
}
```

Comment: That one time I don't put my variables on the top! Thank you my savior!

Comment: The OP shows no call to `startCrash()` in the posted code so how you can you discern that their call is in the wrong place?  Are you just making a lucky guess?

Comment: He mentioned this in a comment for the question. That call should be included in the code to make it clear. I submitted a suggestion for edition

Comment: Note that `clearInterval(this)` does not work because `this` is not the timer handle.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's true. He has to assign the return of `setInterval` to a variable and use  it as parameter of `clearInterval`. It indeed does not work in the way it is now

Comment: Why don't you edit your answer to show that fix too?

Comment: @jfriend00 Just did this :)